# docker run python from container

Tags: docker

I took over a project which requires the usage of docker to setup the development environment. The project wiki is primarily written for use with coreos and one of the setup steps involved running a python script.

I'm using boot2docker and realised that there's no python pre-installed with the tcl. However, the image that I've pulled from the project repository comes with python27.

How do I use the python interpreter from the container without having to type `docker exec` everytime?

Also, how do I access the project code in the boot2docker vm (not docker) instance locally so that I can do development on an IDE?

Comment: Ha, most of the time people want to close Docker questions on SO and send them to SF :)

Comment: @AdrianMouat see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stackoverflow-or-serverfault-or-superuser

Comment: @Thomasleveil I know. But have a look at the number of Docker questions with a close flag (probably from the same one or two users to be fair).

Comment: I'm using http://dockershell.io/ for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use the python interpreter from the container without having to type docker exec everytime?

What about opening a shell in that container instead?

```
docker exec -it <your container id> /bin/bash -l
```

and then from there use python.

> Also, how do I access the project code in the boot2docker vm (not docker) instance locally so that I can do development on an IDE?

I'm not using boot2docker myself but from [this note](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume), it seems it can be done given that the files on your host are in the `/Users` (OSX) or `C:\Users` (Windows) directory

> Note: If you are using Boot2Docker, your Docker daemon only has limited access to your OSX/Windows filesystem. Boot2Docker tries to auto-share your `/Users` (OSX) or `C:\Users` (Windows) directory - and so you can mount files or directories using `docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...` (OSX) or `docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path ...` (Windows). All other paths come from the Boot2Docker virtual machine's filesystem.